# capistrano log message ordering

Tags: logging, capistrano

log messages about execution of remote commands and "normal" messages I put out with 'puts' are not guaranteed to appear in the terminal in the order that they appear in my capistrano script.

does anybody know how to enforce syncing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `STDOUT.sync` or another form of `IO.sync` would be of help.